# Alternate output source for Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have an Arduino sketch that uses the Serial-out as a buffer for a music program. I need to read values from the analog pins and save them based on certain criteria. However, Serial.print does not work as it is used as a buffer, as mentioned before. I tried to use Terminal (using screen), but I found that I cannot write to the Serial output at all (it creates errors in the music program). I cannot modify the music program, so I need to find some alternate way to save my analog inputs. Where can I print the text or perhaps pipe it?

Most of the ways needed to save data in alternate forms use Serial to dump the data and then process it. In my case, Serial itself is unavailable.

Comment: What Music software is it so we can know what format it is expecting. But have you tried Serial.write()? It doesn't encode the data as ascii - just raw bytes which is more common professionally.

Comment: the Firmata code uses Serial.write() to write data to the Serial stream. That's why I cannot write anything to the serial stream. Anything I write is used by the music program, which produces different tones than intended.